# Reuse the same function in 2 Verilog modules

Tags: function, design-patterns, verilog, system-verilog, code-reuse

I have a function `f()`, defined in a Verilog module, `M1`. I would like to reuse this same function in a different module, `M2`.

Is there anyway of doing this without redefining the function in `M2`?

```
  --- M1.v ---
  module M1();
     function f;
        //do stuff
     endfunction
  endmodule

  --- M2.v -----
  module M2();
  // Use f() here
  endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the function into a separate file and use the **`include** compiler directive to include the function inside both modules:

```
  --- M1.v ---
  module M1();
     `include "functions.v"
  endmodule

  --- M2.v -----
  module M2();
     `include "functions.v"
     // Use f() here
  endmodule
```